# MinGW C++ compiler cant find OpenCV in the system path although it is there

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, cmake, mingw

i want to use opencv with Mingw in VScode windows.

i installed everything(Mingw, opencv 3.4.16 with the build library for mingw, cmake), i adjusted the the cmake file, but when i try to run the code the program gives me an error that there is no such file (the included open cv library), although i can navigate to the files that the program cant find from the program it self.

```
include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include<opencv2/core.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**) 
{
    string  path="C:\\Users/Shady/Pictures/Capture.PNG";
    Mat img = imread(path,IMREAD_COLOR);
    if(img.empty())
    {
        cout<<"could not read the image"<<endl;
        return 0 ;
    }
    imshow("Image",img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}
```

cmaklist file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(TryVec VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS /opencv NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(TryVec main.cpp)

target_link_libraries( TryVec ${OpenCV_LIBS} )


set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

system path have both bin and lib for open cv

thats the output after saving cmakelist file

```
[main] Configuring folder: TryVect 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe "-Sf:/Code PlayArea/TryVect" "-Bf:/Code PlayArea/TryVect/build" -G "MinGW Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: F:/Code PlayArea/TryVect/build
```

i tried to add -I before include in system path and -L in system path before lib.

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** which represents *textual* information. Instead, paste the code (`CMakeLists.txt`) and the error message into the question post as **text**. See [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.

Comment: You removed your images, but did not replace them _all_ with transcribed text. Crucially, you didn't add back [the one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Qf5.png) that shows the (compiler) error message: about `#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>` failing. Please [edit] to add that transcription.